How to use IOControlCode.BindToInterface in my socket in .NET?
I'm trying to bind a socket in .NET to a specific network interface. Looking at the IOControlCode documentation, I can see that I could use BindToInterface (SIO_INDEX_BIND) or UnicastInterface (SIO_UCAST_IF) paired with the IOControl method for that. However, when I try using any of those options, I get the following exception:
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 'The attempted operation is not supported for the type of object referenced'

I tried looking for documentation online on how to use those options, but found nothing useful. Can someone enlighten me on how to use them properly?
PS: I don't want to use the Bind method on my socket because it binds to a specific IP address, and I need to bind my socket to a network interface instead. I'm running my code on Windows 11 OS.
I tried binding the socket with the following code:
var uri = new Uri("http://example.com");
// Create and connect a dual-stack socket
Socket socket = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, System.Net.Sockets.ProtocolType.Tcp);
// Interface index is 7
socket.IOControl(IOControlCode.BindToInterface, BitConverter.GetBytes(7), null);
socket.Connect(uri.Host, 80);

But got the exception mentioned above. I was expecting it to work and to bind the socket to the interface.

A Socket type cannot be changed once the connection is establish.  You are making a TCP connection and you cannot bind a UCAST to a TCP connection.

@jdweng I see. Can you give me an example on how to use this property on the IOControl method properly? I used the code on the question because it was the simplest use case I could think of.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.iocontrol?view=net-8.0#system-net-sockets-socket-iocontrol(system-net-sockets-iocontrolcode-system-byte()-system-byte())

@jdweng I meant to say how do I use IOControl with the SIO_INDEX_BIND property without getting the error I'm having. I couldn't find anything useful online so far.

Look at example for IOControl.  I think the 2nd parameter should be null and the 3rd parameter should be the output of the Bind.  The Read method should be similar to the bind method.
